# clover@eclipse : tests not relaunched at new build

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, code-coverage, clover

I am trying to use clover (), a unit-testing plugin for Eclipse, but I wonder about the utility of the option "toggle whether clover instrumentation is performed during compilation for the selected project".

I guessed it has the purpose of launch again the tests and the code coverage after a SAVE option and the following build, but in a dummy project a modification followed by a new build makes the color of the text under test becoming red, but if I modify again the test (this time by setting the test in order to pass) the code coverage stays red, and the tests aren't launched again.

Am I missing something? Is this behavior the correct one? (I mean continuous testing and nearly real time code coverage, at least at each saving).

I use Eclipse Neon, JDK 8 x64 for Windows.

Comment: If an update is an option for you: Eclipse Oxygen has built-in code coverage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=252s

Comment: yes, that's interesting, but in fact I am searching for. continuous testing tools inside eclipse